# Iterating over pairs of items in a list shifting according to a step and increment the step at each iteration (in python)

Tags: python, list, iteration

*Hi folks,

I am looking for some guidance please. For a list of n integer items, I want to iterate over its pairs sequentially and incrementing the step/gap between them for each iteration.

To be clearer and avoid ambiguity, for a list [3,6,7,2,4,9]

First iteration compares (3,6),(6,7),(7,2),(2,4),(4,9)
Second iteration compares (3,7),(6,2),(7,4),(2,9)
Third iteration compares (3,2),(6,4),(7,9)…and so on and so forth.

I am struggling to come up with a solution to maintain the start element in the list but compare in steps of two, three and so on. The code to do the first iteration is as follows (I could have used the zip function) but I am stuck on the next phases, namely how to increment the step by two and three for the next iteration. I wonder is there a way to break out of the while loop and amend the variable step? (I have tried but python is obviously complaining as I am operating within one scope).

```
def pairs_func(l):
    i = 0
    step = 1
    while step < len(l):
        print(l[i])
        print(l[step])
        i = i + 1
        step = step + 1
```

Thanks in advance.
F

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt the famous [`pairwise()` iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) to have a `gap` argument:

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable, gap=1):
    "s -> (s0,s{gap}), (s1,s{gap+1}), (s2, s{gap+2}), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    for i in range(gap):
        next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
```

Usage:

```
>>> a = [3, 6, 7, 2, 4, 9]

>>> list(pairwise(a))
[(3, 6), (6, 7), (7, 2), (2, 4), (4, 9)]

>>> list(pairwise(a, 2))
[(3, 7), (6, 2), (7, 4), (2, 9)]
```

Or, if you prefer to use it in a loop:

```
for gap in range(1, len(a)):
    for x, y in pairwise(a, gap):
        print(f'work with x={x} and y={y}')

# output:
work with x=3 and y=6
work with x=6 and y=7
work with x=7 and y=2
work with x=2 and y=4
work with x=4 and y=9
work with x=3 and y=7
work with x=6 and y=2
work with x=7 and y=4
work with x=2 and y=9
work with x=3 and y=2
work with x=6 and y=4
work with x=7 and y=9
work with x=3 and y=4
work with x=6 and y=9
work with x=3 and y=9
```

Comment: Thanks Pierre, I shall give this a try